# Different ways to say “I have some”

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs, formulation-idiomatique

Is “J'en ai” the best way to say “I have some”?

What's the difference between “J'en ai” and, “j'ai un peu”, or “j'ai quelque chose”?

Comment: "j'en ai un peu" = i have a little (of that thing we were talking about) "j'en ai" = i have some (of that thing we were talking about). "j'ai un peu" is ungrammatical.

Comment: As @hunter mentions, “j’en ai un peu” adds the notion of “a little” when discussing [uncountable] things. To add the notion of “a few” when discussing countable nouns or people, “J’en ai quelques-uns/quelques-unes” would perhaps be better than “J’en ai un peu”: “Du vin? Oui, j’en ai un peu.”--“Des bouteilles de vin/copains? Oui, j’en ai quelques-unes/-uns.” Just as “J’ai un peu” alone is incorrect (as mentioned by hunter & jlliagre), “j’ai quelques-un(e)s” would perhaps also be wrong w/out either the “en” or else a following “de” clause (not sure about any of this so please don’t quote me!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***J'en ai*** is a good translation of "**I have some**".

***J'ai un peu*** alone is incorrect, you should state what it is about, e.g.:

***J'ai un peu d'argent*** -> **I have some money**.

***J'ai quelque chose*** is correct French but while ***j'en ai*** is used when your party knows exactly what you are talking about, ***J'ai quelque chose*** is used to state you have something but without telling precisely what it is, i.e. "**I have something**".